# Bootable Linux partition alongside an NTFS partition on USB flashdrive

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning, usb-flash-drive

On a 128 GB flashdrive, in order to boot Linux from the drive I created two `ext4` partitions (`/` and `/home`, Linux installed on the root partition) and a `swap` partition as well as a `NTFS` partition that I would like to use when I'm using the flashdrive on a booted Windows system.

Here are the partitioning details:

[image]

How would I manage to have the bootloader automatically recognize the `ext4` root partition when booting from the flashdrive while having Windows automatically recognize the `NTFS` partition when I insert the flashdrive on a booted Windows system?

Currently, I need to switch back and forth between the partition that is accessible (with [BOOTICE](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/bootice.html)) depending whether or not I'm using the flashdrive for booting Linux or as a data flashdrive on Windows. Choosing the *NTFS* partition to be the accessible one in Windows means Linux won't boot and choosing the *ext4* root partition to be the accessible one means Linux boots just fine, but Windows in turn won't show me the *NTFS* partition

---

### Update

I was asked to provide additional information about the HDD/SDD that Windows is intalled on.

It's a Windows 8.1 installation as shipped by Dell (XPS 15) that was upgraded to a Windows 10 installation. As I didn't install it myself, I'm not exactly sure about details such as UEFI etc.

Here are the partitioning details of that drive:

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot from Gparted of the Windows-drive too ?

Comment: The last partition shown in the screenshot is the NTFS partition

Comment: Yes ,sure that is shown in your screenshot. We need more information. How is Windows installed , UEFI-mode or legacy-mode. Please provide information about the Windows-drive too, otherwise it is not possible to give correct advice.

Comment: @mook765: I updated the post. Let me know if you need further information.

Comment: Windows is installed in UEFI-mode. How is Linux installed? We cant see that from Gparted. Boot to Linux, run following command in terminal:`[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS` and post back the result. Did you assign a drive-letter to the NTFS-partition on the linux-drive? If not, then do that from within Windows, use the built-in disk-manager or any third-party partition-manager.